# ASP .NET MVC 5 Filter get View.ViewBag data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I need log all GET request url + page.Title. Page title set in _Layout.cshtml as

```c#
<title>@ViewBag.Title - @S.AppName</title>
```

ViewBag.Title set in View.cshtml

```c#
ViewBag.Title = S.MemberDayReports;
```

I try use custom ActionFilterAttribute. In OnResultExecuted(..) ViewBag.Title is null.

I try override in controller OnResultExecuted but ViewBag.Title is null.

How intercept view output and log ViewBag.Title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override WebViewPage

```c#
public abstract class WebViewPageAdv<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            var title = String.Format("{0} - {1}", ViewBag.Title, S.AppName);
            //Because Title get in _Layout.cshtml its full page load
            //and can log user GET request
            return title;
        }
    }
}
```

Views\web.config

```xml
<pages pageBaseType="WebViewPageAdv">
```

_Layout.cshtml

```c#
<title>@this.Title</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

Viewbag main purpose is controller to view communication. Value are set to null after redirection.TempData keep the information for the time of an HTTP Request. This mean only from one page to another.Tye to use temp data .

or also you can update a static variable for title in each post/get. Fro this purpose you can use filter to track current and last data. ViewBag wont fullfill your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewBag` description in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx) describes where ViewBag is used for:

> The ViewBag property enables you to dynamically share values **from the
>   controller to the view**. It is a dynamic object which means it has no
>   pre-defined properties. You define the properties you want the ViewBag
>   to have by simply adding them to the property. In the view, you
>   retrieve those values by using same name for the property.

If you change the property of the `ViewBag` in the View is not returned back to the pipeline and it is not visible in either filters or controller.

As a workaround you can set `Title` property in the view - in this case it would be visible both in filters and in controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Your title";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Good solution but requires change all Actions

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked if values set in the controller are readable this way, but you can set the viewbag like

```cs
public class FilterNameHere : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.propertyNameHere = "value here";
    }
}
```

Then register the filter as a GlobalFilter via GlobalAsax such as

```cs
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new FilterNameHere());
```